# Delphi 7 boolean equations aren't working

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, boolean-expression

I have a program written in Delphi 7 that appears to be experiencing some logic issues.  the following line never gives a true value even when my watch window says it should.

```
Seq^.step[1] := 
  (PlcStart^ and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or 
  (RetryDelay^.Done and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or 
  (Seq^.Step[1] and (not Seq^.Step[reset_]));
```

my watch window shows that `(PlcStart^ and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or (RetryDelay^.Done and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or (Seq^.Step[1] and (not Seq^.Step[reset_]))` is true but the value of `Seq^.Step[1]` never gets set to true.

The real strange part is that I have a number of programs with the exact same line that all appear to be working correctly.

Comment: Looks like you've discovered a compiler bug! Or perhaps not. Try and do some debugging. Prove to us that the Delphi logic expression evaluator is broken.

Comment: Try breaking your expression into 3 variables, and evaluate each step separately.

Comment: I don't think that compiler fails on such expression. Maybe compiler can see in search paths another version of the unit or unit is changed but compiler uses old DCU, ... Try to build project without compiler optimization and execute it in CPU debug window instruction by instruction. That way you can make sure that compiler really compile that code and you will see how calculations done step by step.

Comment: Is "Project > Options > Delphi Compiler > Compiling > Syntax options > Complete boolean evaluation" set to the same value in both projects?

Answer (score 0):

> Seq^.step[1] := 
>     (PlcStart^ and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or 
>     (RetryDelay^.Done and (not Seq^.Step[2])) or 
>     (Seq^.Step[1] and (not Seq^.Step[reset_]));

I'm not familiar with Delphi but I am familiar with boolean logic. If I'm reading this right your're saying:

(A ∧ ¬B) ∨ (C ∧ ¬B) ∨ (D ∧ ¬E)

in javascript that's:

```
(a && !b) || (c && !b) || (d && !e)
```

Using http://mustpax.github.io/Truth-Table-Generator/ to generate a truth table and converting "false" to "0" and "true" to "1", we get the truth table:

```
a b c d e (a & !b) | (c & !b) | (d & !e)
1 1 1 1 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
1 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 1 1 1 1
1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 0 1 1 0
1 0 0 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 0
1 1 1 0 1 0
0 1 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1 1
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 0 0 1 0
0 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 0 1 1
0 0 0 0 1 0
1 1 1 1 0 1
0 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 1
1 1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
1 0 1 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 1
1 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

This table may or may not be correct, I haven't verified it. You can go through it and decide for yourself. Anyway, assuming it is correct, you could check the expected output for your given input and verify whether your expectations are correct.